# translating prototypejs ajax request to libcurl in C++

Tags: ajax, libcurl, prototypejs

I have an ajax request in prototype js that basically goes like this:

```
new Ajax.Request("http://www.example.com", {
    method: 'post',
    postBody: '{"params":{"first":"one", "second":"two"}}',
    contentType: 'text/json'  
    requestHeaders: {  
        'Content-Length': 42  
    }  
    onComplete: function() {}  
});
```

I tried doing this in libcurl like so:

```
struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;
slist = curl_slist_append(slist, "Content-Type: text/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, slist);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 42);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS, "{\"params\":{\"first\":\"one\", \"second\":\"two\"}}");
```

But on the server side it doesn't recognize the post body as it does with the prototype implementation.

I haven't been able to make any progress on this, so I'm hoping someone here can provide the insight I need to continue. Thanks!

Comment: There are `,` missing in your AJAX request (before onComplete and requestHeader)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Prototype detects that postBody is written in JSON and converts it into URL-Encoding before sending it to the server (and libcurl doesn't). You could install Firebug to see what happens.

Try to send the following as postBody / in libcurl:

```
params[first]=one&params[second]=two
```

Comment: Prototype treats `postBody` as a string and doesn't manipulate it at all, just passes it [straight to the XHR object](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/1fb9728/src/ajax/request.js#L212) of that browser. [`parameters`](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/) is inspected and converted to an URL-encoded string if necessary.

Comment: Reading the code (thank you): the JSON-String wouldn't get URL-encoded even as a `parameters`: only a hash would.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea would be to add the headers that Prototype [sends by default](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/1fb9728/src/ajax/request.js#L233-235) to libcurl:

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
X-Prototype-Version: (Prototype.Version)
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
```